# Using RequireJS to load dojo modules

Tags: javascript, dojo, requirejs, arcgis-js-api

I am hosting ArcGIS JS API 4.1 locally in my project, so I have build the esri componenet and I have added the path in my requireJS config file. I also wanted to build the dojo folder, so basically build it to a single output file. But when I add the dojo modules using requireJS bundles I get an error in the esri file that e is not a function(…). The line of code that it appears on is:

```
define("dojo/_base/config", ["../has", "require"], function(e, t) {
    var r = {};
    if (e("dojo-config-api")) { ... }  //e is undefined.
```

I get that the error means dojo/has is undefined but I don't understand why. I tried using dojo/has in my project and it is not undefined but in the esri file it says its undefined. Does anybody know how I can fix this.

This is requireJS config file:

```
requirejs.config({
    paths: {
        "jquery": 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min',
        'esri/moment': 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.14.1/moment',
        "esri": "../lib/arcgis-js-api-4/main",
       "dojo": "../lib/arcgis-js-api-4/dojo-lib",
       "dojox": 'http://js.arcgis.com/4.1/dojox',
       "dijit": 'http://js.arcgis.com/4.1/dijit'
},
bundles: {
        "esri": ["esri/Color",...],
      'dojo': ['dojo/has', 'dojo/domReady',...]
},shim: {
    "esri": {
            deps: ["esri/moment", "dojo", "dojox", "dijit"]
        }
}
});
```

This is the config for the dojo build:

```
var profile=(function(){
    return {
        basePath: "./",
        releaseDir: "./",
        releaseName: "dojoLib",
        action: "release",
        cssOptimize: 'comments',
        layerOptimize: false,
        packages:[{
                name: "dojo",
                location: "src/dojo"
            }],
        layers:{
            "dojo/dojoLib": {
                include: ["dojo/dojo", "dojo/i18n", "dojo/domReady", 'dojo/has', 'dojo/request', 'dojo/request/xhr',
                'dojo/request/util', 'dojo/request/watch', 'dojo/io/script', 'dojo/io/iframe', 'dojo/query'],
                customBase: true,
                boot: false    
            }
        }
    };
})();
```

Comment: The first thing that comes to mind is that in the file throwing the error, the path is relative (`../has`) so maybe the location of the esri vs dojo folders is not what that code expected? Do you still get the error if you just include `dojo/has` (absolute path)?

Comment: @Corina thats what I thought at first so I tried changing it to dojo/has and it still throws the same error.